# Unable to execute events in separate class

Tags: java, selenium, testing, appium

```
**Here are the classes i am using.**
```

Actions used here in homepage class is not working. i call this class after setup class.

```
 public class HomePage {

        AndroidDriver driver;

        public  void switchToFlightBook() throws InterruptedException
        {

            WebElement allow2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@resource-id='com.cleartrip.android:id/switcher_image']"));

            allow2.click();
            System.out.println("allowed");
    }
    }
```

This is setup class which i am using to launch the appium. so what ever action like click and all i am using here are working fine but when i use same actions in homepage class it is not working.

```
  public class Setup {

         AndroidDriver<WebElement> driver;

        public void launchAppium() throws MalformedURLException {
            File apkFilePath = new File("/Users/practo/Documents/workspace/cleartrip/apps/Cleartrip.apk");
            File app = new File(apkFilePath, "Cleartrip.apk");

            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setCapability("device", "Android");
            capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Raj");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
            capabilities.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);
            capabilities.setCapability("autoDismissAlerts", true);
            capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0.1");

            driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);


            WebElement allow2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@resource-id='com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button']"));
            allow2.click();

        }
    }



public class SearchPageTest {   
    @Test
    public void VerifySearchPage() throws InterruptedException 
    {
        HomePage homepage = new HomePage(); 
        homepage.switchToFlightBook();
    }
    @BeforeTest
      public void beforeTest() throws MalformedURLException 
    {
          System.out.println("Starting setup");
          Setup setup = new Setup();
          setup.launchAppium();
          System.out.println("Setup is done");
      }
    @AfterTest
      public void afterTest() {
          System.out.println("Test case completed");
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're not initializing the `driver` member of the `HomePage` class. If that's the case, just pass it as a constructor argument to your `HomePage` class:

```
public class HomePage {
  AndroidDriver driver;

  public HomePage(AndroidDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
  }

  public void switchToFlightBook() throws InterruptedException { ... }
}
```

To make that work with the rest of the architecture you presented, you would have to return the driver from the `launchAppium` method of your `Setup` class, store it in a member of the `SearchPageTest` class and pass it on where you instantiate the `HomePage` class.

Comment: This is really helpful. I was able to solve the problem. Thanks